# Looking to identify this species

Tags: species-identification, invertebrates, arthropod

I found a rather strange invertebrate...something... outside my home this evening, and I have no idea what it might be. It looks kind of like a small brown lobster, without the claws. I think it has 8 legs, making it an arthropod(?), but if I've misidentified that, please correct the tags. It's 4 or 5 inches long, head to tail. It was found in south-eastern Massachusetts. Potential nearby habitats are open grassy fields, a forest, and a cranberry bog, if that helps.

[image]

The picture is kinda fuzzy, I think the [video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/m2UxU8zWCrCTV3ff6) is better.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but [crayfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crayfish) seems plausible to me.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I suggest you to take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about this site and earn yourself your first badge. Have a nice stay!

Comment: @mgkrebbs crayfish is what other people elsewhere are suggesting as well. It was pretty cool, I'd never seen one before.

Comment: Yep, it's a crayfish ... given the locality and assuming it's native to the area, we're looking at a member of the family Cambaridae, which has dozens of genera and hundreds of species north of Mexico (and requires that you have a "first-form male" for genus level identification: see _How to Know the Freshwater Crustaceans_, if you can find a copy).